# If $R$ has zero divisors and $M$ is an $R$ module, is every element of $M$ torsion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Supposing $R$ has zero divisors, there are elements $a,b \neq 0_R$ such that $ab = 0_R$.

Letting $m\in M$ be arbitrary, it seems to be the case that 
$$
ab \cdot m = 0_R \cdot M = 0_M.
$$

So as long as there is at least one zero divisor in $R$, every element of $M$ is torsion. Is this in fact true, or is there a subtlety that I am missing?

Comment: This does not imply that every element of $M$ is torsion. Take $m \in M$, you know that $(ab)m=0$, but this does not show that $m$ is torsion, since $(ab)$ is a fancy way to denote $0$. To show that $m$ is torsion, you need to find some *nonzero* element $r \in R$ such that $r \cdot m=0$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for a ring which is not an integral domain, a torsion element in a module is an element $m$ such that $am=0$ for some $a$ *which is not a zero divisor*. In other words it is in the kernel of the canonical map $\;M\longrightarrow M\otimes_R Q$, where $Q$ is the total ring of fractions of $R$.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ as a $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$-module, then $1$ is not a torsion

Comment: Ah @Crostul I see what I was missing -- so $bm$ will be torsion for every $m$, but not every element of $M$ is of this form.

Comment: Also, thanks for the counterexamples, and I hadn't seen the formulation using tensor products before so I'll read up on that a bit. I'd happily accept any of these as answers FYI.